# Gradle: начиная с какой версии появились system properties?

Tags: gradle

В какой версии Gradle появилась возможность задавать [system properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_properties_and_system_properties) используя ключ **`-D`** в command line?
Например:

```
gradle war -Dkey=value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Этот ключ использует JVM. Так что он в gradle с первой доступной (на настоящий момент) версии 0.7.

[Gradle Command Line v0.7](https://docs.gradle.org/0.7/userguide/gradle_command_line.html)